# Pegar primeiro elemento da linha e ultimo

Tags: html, css, css3, css-hover

Tenho uma li e queria pegar os elementos que estão escritos MARCADO abaixo. 
Porém usei o nth-of-type, funciona para pegar o 4 elemento sempre, porém não consegui fazer pegar o próximo. 
Alguém conseguiria me ajudar a pegar sempre 1 depois do primeiro item onde está escrito marcado?

```css
 ul li&:nth-of-type(1){color: red;}
 ul li&:nth-of-type(4n){color: red;}
```

```html
<ul>   
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
   <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
   <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
   <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
   <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
   <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
   <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
   <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
   <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
   <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
   <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
   <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
   <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para o seu caso, você precisa pegar a cada 5 elementos, e não a cada 4 elementos, desta forma você também vai fazer um seletor para o elemento anterior (5n - 1)

```css
ul li:nth-of-type(1){color: red;}
ul li:nth-of-type(5n - 1){color: red;}
ul li:nth-of-type(5n){color: red;}
```

```html
<ul>   
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!!

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar o `:nth-child` assim:

```css
ul li:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) {
  color: red;
}
ul li:nth-child(5) {
  color: red;
}
ul li:nth-child(9) {
  color: red;
}
ul li:nth-child(10) {
  color: red;
}
ul li:nth-child(14) {
  color: red;
}
ul li:nth-child(15) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number MARCADO</li>
  <li class="col-sm-3">number</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Essas LI's podem ser cadastráveis, ou seja, podem ter milhoes de li's. 
Aí não ocnseguiria fazer assim.

Comment: Qual é o padrão ? se você deseja uma sim/outra não você pode usar `ul li:nth-child(2n){
    color: red;
} 
`

Comment: Se não tiver um padrão certo e somente houver uma marcação no texto indicando que ela deva possuir tal configuração acredito que você terá que verificar o valor com javascript e adicionar o css