# Como pegar a primeira e a ultima class parent de uma div contida dentro de uma TD via CSS/SASS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, front-end

Gostaria de saber como faz para pegar o primeiro e o ultimo parent de um conjunto de classe (.date) que esta contida em uma div dentro de um elemento .

Segue exemplo de trexo de código:

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Sobrenome</td>
        <td>Data Nascimento</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="range">Thiago</td>
        <td class="range">Cunha</td>
        <td class="range">
            <div class="date">
                22/12/1988
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="range">Caroline</td>
        <td class="range">Cunha</td>
        <td class="range">
            <div class="date">
                22/12/1988
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="range">Thalita</td>
        <td class="range">Cunha</td>
        <td class="range">
            <div class="date">
                22/12/1988
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="range">Thiago</td>
        <td class="range">Cunha</td>
        <td class="range">22/12/1988</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="range">Caroline</td>
        <td class="range">Cunha</td>
        <td class="range">
            <div class="date">
                22/12/1988
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="range">Thalita</td>
        <td class="range">Cunha</td>
        <td class="range">
            <div class="date">
                22/12/1988
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

Reparem que no código, apenas algumas divs recebem a classe .date.

Grato pela a colaboração.

Comment: Relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111535/pegar-primeiro-elemento-da-linha-e-ultimo

Comment: Eu cheguei dar uma olhada, mas ainda não é isso!

Comment: Não seria uma opção criar uma classe e colocar na primeira e na última .data? Tipo class="data primeira"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc consegue, mas para isso vc precisa selecionar a `TR` e não a `div`, isso se deve por uma questão de hierarquia de seletores.

Então primeiro vc precisa seleciona a sua **segunda** `TR`, pois a primeira é onde estão os títulos das colunas e não as datas, e depois selecionar a **última** `TR` onde tem a última data.

Depois vc usa as pseudo-classe `nth-child(2)` e `last-child` para chegar nas datas que vc quer customizar.

Veja o exemplo para entender melhor, ***sempre a primeira e última data estarão com a cor diferente***, não importa a quantidade de conteúdo entre a primeira data e a última. Deixei os *comments* no código css.

```css
/* pega sempre a segunda última TD da segunda TR e  troca a cor da classe .date */
tr:nth-child(2) > td:last-child .date {
  color: red;
}
/* pega sempre a última TD da última TR e troca a cor da classe .date */
tr:last-child > td:last-child .date {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Sobrenome</td>
        <td>Data Nascimento</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="range">Thiago</td>
        <td class="range">Cunha</td>
        <td class="range">
            <div class="date">
                22/12/1988
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="range">Caroline</td>
        <td class="range">Cunha</td>
        <td class="range">
            <div class="date">
                22/12/1988
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="range">Thalita</td>
        <td class="range">Cunha</td>
        <td class="range">
            <div class="date">
                22/12/1988
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="range">Thiago</td>
        <td class="range">Cunha</td>
        <td class="range">22/12/1988</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="range">Caroline</td>
        <td class="range">Cunha</td>
        <td class="range">
            <div class="date">
                22/12/1988
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="range">Thalita</td>
        <td class="range">Cunha</td>
        <td class="range">
            <div class="date">
                22/12/1988
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>
```